# TeamCity SilverLight application Build Error

Tags: .net, silverlight, msbuild, teamcity

```
GetFrameworkPaths 

ValidateSilverlightFrameworkPaths 

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v5.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets(104, 9): The Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed.
```

Above is the error message I am receiving from TeamCity build agent, which says I will need to install the SilverLight 4 SDK.

Then I download the SilverLight 4 SDK and get it installed, but still TeamCity complains about it.  So what exactly is wrong with this? Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although TeamCity complains about `The Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed`, installing [Silverlight 5 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359) does help resolve this issue.

Comment: We have encountered this situation and installing the Silverlight 5 SDK did not resolve this issue. We are still searching for a solution to make teamcity work with silverlight it seems hideously difficult to get anything to build

Answer (score 0):

If the build agent can't build, load the solution in Visual Studio on the build server and it'll likely give you more information that will help resolve the issue. I had this issue, tried the install SDK 4 and 5 as suggested but it still didn't work. When I loaded in VS on the build server VS complained that it was in fact the Windows Phone 8 SDK that wasn't installed.